# Apache behind Nginx exposes itself because of DirectorySlash redirect

Tags: apache, nginx

I have Apache running on port 8097, and Nginx proxying requests to it:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8097;

    proxy_redirect          off;
    proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    client_max_body_size    10m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_connect_timeout   90;
    proxy_send_timeout      90;
    proxy_read_timeout      90;
    proxy_buffers           32 4k;
}
```

Apache config (meaningful part):

```
    <Directory /home/some/htdocs>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            Options -Indexes
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

So what happens: when I go to `www.mysite.com/photos` and there exists a directory `photos` Apache redirects me to this directory with slash added. But for some reason it actually redirects me to `www.mysite.com:8097/photos/` I see this address in the browser, what I am actually not supposed to:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.2.4
Date: Thu, 01 Nov 2012 10:28:13 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://www.mysite.com:8097/photos/
```

I know I can fix this via `UseCanonicalName On` (not the best solution - what if i do not have a canonical name?) But still I wonder, how it happens that the actual apache port is exposed with this kind of redirect (but all other rewrites and redirects work properly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to fix it in nginx config. One need to add port to Host header

```
proxy_set_header        Host            $host:$server_port;
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds silly but your browser may have cached the 301. i had a similar issue solved by opening in another browser.

at first look your config looks fine

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case. Thanks for your suggestion.